service worker takes much time to register
why service workers takes too much time to respond?
I have registered the service worker in react vite application.but it takes too much time to be registered.
Here's my service worker file (placed in plublic folder)
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js");
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-messaging.js"
);

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker
// "Default" Firebase configuration (prevents errors)
const defaultConfig = {
  apiKey: true,
  projectId: true,
  messagingSenderId: true,
  appId: true,
};

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "XXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXXX",
    measurementId:'XXXXXX'
});

// Retrieve firebase messaging
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
    icon: payload.notification.image,
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});

Here's the firebaseconfig file
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

//Firebase Config values imported from .env file
export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXXX",
    measurementId:'XXXXXX'
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export async function requestPermission() {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(async (permission) => {
        if (permission === 'granted') {
            console.log('permission granted')
            if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && window.location.pathname.startsWith(`${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_BASENAME}`)) {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register(`.${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_BASENAME}/firebase-messaging-sw.js`, {scope: `${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_BASENAME}/`}) // Path to service worker file
                  .then(registration => {
                    console.log('Service Worker registered successfully:', registration);
                    return getToken(messaging, {
                        vapidKey: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_VAPID_KEY,
                        serviceWorkerRegistration: registration,
                    }).then(token => {
                        if (token) {
                            console.log('token', token)
                            localStorage.setItem('deviceToken', token)
                        } else {
                            console.log('failed to generate token')
                        }
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.log("an error occured", err)
                    })
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Service Worker registration failed:', error);
                  });
              }
        } else {
            console.log('permission denied')
        }
    })
}

requestPermission();
// Messaging service
export const messaging = getMessaging(app);

what should be done for speed up the service workers as this takes long for getting the device token for firebase cloud messaging.
Thanks in advance
